# Problem with printer Canon LBP6000B (i-SENSYS)

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon

I have printer Canon LBP6000 and I tried to add printer from `System Settings` -> `Printing`. So I can add that printer but when I tried to print test page it doesn't printing. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the Canon driver following the instructions here: [CanonCaptDrv190](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190)

(Basically, it does not work as some kernel modules used by the Canon driver are "blacklisted", i.e. prevented from loading, by default).